# Setting response model via Serverless framework for AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am trying to set up my AWS API Gateway via the Serverless Framework. So far it works good but no I am struggling setting the method response as a model. I got it working for the request but not for the response and I haven't found a hint in the documentation.

```
      ...
      request:
        passThrough: NEVER
        schema:
          application/json: ${file(requestModel.json)}
        template:
          application/json: ${file(requestMapping.template)}
      response:
        headers:
          Content-Type: "'application/json'"
        template: $input.body
      ...
```

If I include a schema in the response, it is ignored...

Comment: Can you link the docs you used for the request section.

Comment: Re. response, checked https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway and not finding anything specific about models. (have similar question as you atm).